# Exception thrown at 0x00007FF63C04254B in Elements.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++

I have a couple of arrays in my main.cpp, as seen here:

```cpp
...
Element* screen, *buffer;
screen = new Element[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT];
buffer = new Element[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT];
memset(screen, 0, GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT * sizeof(Element));
memset(buffer, 0, GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT * sizeof(Element));
...
```

And, in a my elem.cpp there is a function that uses one of these arrays:

```cpp
void drawElements(Element* screen[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT]) {
    for (int x = 1; x < GAME_WIDTH - 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < GAME_HEIGHT - 2; y++) {
            std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)]->id << std::endl; //Temporary, problem here
        
        }
    }
}
```

While all this *should* do is just print 0 a bunch of times currently, instead it throws the exception shown in the title of this question when debugged, right where the comment is in the elem.cpp code snippet. I've read that this can be caused by not initializing an object, but I *think* that they are initialized, as they are created and all set to 0 in the main.cpp code snippet.

I'm fairly new to pointers and such, so it is entirely possible that this problem arises from some simple quirk of pointers and references, but i'm not quite sure what is going on.

Here is the definition of the Element struct:

```cpp
struct Element {
    int id;
    float lifetime;
    int density;
};
```

And for he who requested it, here is my attempt at a minimal reproducible example of my problem, it throws the same exception when ran through the VC++ debugger.

```cpp
struct Broken {
    int x = 20;
};
void doSomething(Broken* borked[10000]) {
    for (int x = 1; x < 10000 - 1; x++) {
        std::cout << borked[x]->x << std::endl; //Throws exception here
    }
}
int main()
{
    Broken* borked;
    borked = new Broken[10000];
    memset(borked, 0, 10000 * sizeof(Broken));

    doSomething(&borked);

}
```

Comment: What is Element?  I suspect it isn't a POD.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Element is a very simple struct

Comment: "very simple" is not an adequate description. Add the definition to your question.

Comment: I've added the definition to the question. I'm trying to make the minimal reproducible example that you've sent, but it's taking some time because i'm not exactly sure whats causing the problem. I'll edit into the question when I get it, though

Comment: what does idx(x,y) do? if youre accessing out of bounds youd probably get that error

Comment: idx(x,y) just gets the index of x and y in the array. 
I've also got a small example that that gives the error when debugging, i'll edit into the question.

Comment: I *think* you have an incorrect indirection. And its partially obscured by specifying the array size in the function signature (which decays anyway afaik). In your minimal example, if directly after you allocate your Broken array, you do `borked[x].x;` you'll see that it compiles, but notice that in your function you index the array and still use pointer syntax to get x. Theres a mismatch there and that's causing your crash. https://godbolt.org/z/h17xjsnqd see edited code for details (I dont crash with my edits)

Comment: To my knowledge, in a function signature void foo(Broken* bar[10]) is equivalent to void foo(Broken** bar) but you didnt allocate an array of pointers to Broken, you allocated an array of Broken, the & when passing it to the function is wrong, and so is the function signature. it should either be Broken bar[1000] or Broken* bar.

Comment: Borgleader, that solved my problem, thanks! I'm not sure how to mark it as solved, but i'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

what is declared "single" is a single pointer.

the variable "screen" declared in "drawElements" is a double pointer, not a single pointer. also, when accessing a variable in an array, instead of using the operator->, operator. must be used.

```
Element* screen, *buffer; // <= definition single pointer
screen = new Element[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT]; 

void drawElements(Element* screen[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT]){ // <= this mean double pointer
    for (int x = 1; x < GAME_WIDTH - 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < GAME_HEIGHT - 2; y++) {
            std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)]->id << std::endl; //Invalid variable access
        
        }
    }
}
```

```
// wrong call element
std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)]->id << std::endl;

// correct call element
std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)].id << std::endl;
```

change it in the following way :D

```
void drawElements(Element* screen) {
    for (int x = 1; x < GAME_WIDTH - 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < GAME_HEIGHT - 2; y++) {
            std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)].id << std::endl; //Temporary, problem here
        
        }
    }
}
```

another this

```
void drawElements(Element screen[GAME_WIDTH * GAME_HEIGHT]) {
    for (int x = 1; x < GAME_WIDTH - 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < GAME_HEIGHT - 2; y++) {
            std::cout << screen[idx(x, y)].id << std::endl; //Temporary, problem here
        
        }
    }
}
```

ps. Why did you use a single array in this implementation? In this case, a double array is usually used to separate the width and height.